# Configure REDIS in Gitlab CI/CD for usage in Django

Tags: django, docker, redis, gitlab

I had a working pipeline on GitLab which started failing after I added tests involving REDIS. I've applied (?) what is written [inside GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/redis.html#use-redis-with-the-docker-executor) but still REDIS is not discovered by my tests.

Here's my `gitlab-cy.yml` file:

```html
pep8:
  image: python:latest
  services:
    - postgres:10-alpine
    - redis:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: ci
    DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB"
    REDIS_URL: redis
  stage: test
  script:
    - python -V
    - pip install -r ./requirements/gitlab.txt

    - pytest --pep8
  cache:
    paths:
    - ~/.cache/pip/
```

And here's how I'm using it inside Django:

`REDIS_URL = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/0")
cache = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(url=REDIS_URL)`

I've also set Environment Variables inside CI/CD settings in GitLab  `REDIS_URL` to `redis` however still when the test executes `None` gets assigned to `host` and the test fails ....-> `self = Connection<host=None,port=6379,db=0>`

Any idea how to connect with Redis on GitLab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out, so I'm posting it here if you are also having this problem :)

I removed the `REDIS_URL` variable from `gitlab-ci.yml` and I have added the following variable in GitLab CI Environment variables settings:

`REDIS_URL` -> `redis://redis:6379/0`

which solved the problem :)